# How to implement <blockquote> and <code> on the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to create a textarea exactly like SO textarea when you want write a question / answer. Now almost I did it:

```js
function generate(text) {
  text = text.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
  text = text.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<u>$1</u>");
  text = text.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<i>$1</i>");
  text = text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, "<del>$1</del>");
  text = text.replace(/`(.*?)`/g, "<code>$1</code>");
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<textarea id="Q&A" oninput="generate(this.value)" name="txtarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<div id="out"></div>
```

But I can't create a good regex for replacing `>` with `<blockquote>` and either "`" or `4[space]` replace with `<code>` tags. However I wrote a regex for blockquote:

`text = text.replace(/>(.*?)(\n|$)+/g, "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>");`

But this ^ doesn't work as well. So, can anybody fix it?

Comment: Why not use a markdown parser?

Comment: @MinusFour What? that's a library?

Comment: @stack [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is a language, but there are numerous implementations that you can find and use. You may also consider [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/)-based implementations.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I used of what you suggested to me, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhd8qy6k/2/) is a fiddle of that. May you please check that fiddle and tell me every thing is ok? did I it correctly? Actually it works. But I think I shouldn't define a object into a function ..! However I don't know, I'm newbie in JS. Anyway please just tell me my code is fine or I can do that better? *(beforehand)* thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> However I wrote a regex for blockquote:
>
> `text = text.replace(/>(.*?)(\n|$)+/g, "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>");`
>
> But this ^ doesn't work as well. So, can anybody fix it?

You surely don't want to replace `>` in the middle of a line, so use the boundary character `^` along with the multiline flag `m` (matching the beginning of input and also immediately after a line break):

```
  text = text.replace(/^>(.*?)(\n|$)+/gm, "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>");
```